# Can't Install MariaDB - Dependency Error?

Tags: mariadb

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Digital Ocean VM. I'm trying to install MariaDB 10.1. When doing so, I get the following error:

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.8+maria-1~trusty) ...
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.8+maria-1~trusty); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.1
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is what I've tried to fix this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

AND

restarting the machine

I was searching Stack Exchange and other Linux forms for a while and I cannot figure out what is causing this. I appreciate any help that could be offered!

UPDATE: Here is the output of `apt-get install -f`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.8+maria-1~trusty) ...
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.8+maria-1~trusty); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.1
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f` and post the output.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I pasted the info in the updated question. I looked at the output before, it's not very useful.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Why is this question still here on serverfault or not closed?

Answer (score 4):

Found this in log:

`[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log'`

So I commented out 
conf.d/local.cnf

```
#log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log'
```

And installation finally ends succesfully.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly it, preventing me to upgrade from jessie to stretch

Comment: also was a reason for me.

Comment: where is the log file?

Answer (score 2):

Try backing up all files in /var/lib/mysql somewhere. Delete them all and then execute mysql_install_db.

My problem came from removing mysqld and replacing it with mariadb and trying to keep the database files. All other methods failed for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your system has problems running the (post)configure script of the mariadb-server-10.1 package.

First, try to clean the apt cache using `apt-get clean` and to reinstall the package (please note `apt-get autoclean` only partially clean the cache).

If that fails, you had to use `dpkg -i mariadb-server-10.1` and/or `dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-server-10.1` to give a more in-depth looking at the specific error.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

I know it sounds crazy that rebooting the machine solved the problem on linux, but I doublechecked. However I'm working in my Vagrant machine, not sure for Digital Ocean.

System:

- Debian 7,
- mysql installed from dotdeb with a working database,
- updated MariaDB apt sources and key added,
- install mariadb-server-10.1 which ended with the same error.

After rebooting everything worked, including the DB now served by MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

Refer link below:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249530/mariadb-dependency-problems-leaving-unconfigured

Main>
Install everything from fresh: Add the following to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian jessie main
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing mariadb-server on another pi and moved the dependencies I was missing over.

All the dependencies I was missing were in /etc/mysql

After i did that it installed normally.